# gradlew assemble error: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I'm experiencing a strange error that only happens when I try to build my project using the gradlew script file.

If I run `gradlew assemble` Proguard it's complaining in multiple classes (in the same module) with the following warning:

```
 can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
```

Of course I have the following rule inside my module and main project `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.**
-dontwarn **$$Lambda$*
```

But even with that Proguard it's still complaining about the same warning...

Now the strange part is, if I run a different job, for example `assembleRelease`, `assembleDebug`, or `assembleQA` (A custom job that I make) the process finish without any problem...

I'm getting out of ideas here...

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Code_Life noup not yet